# Laravel 5.1 Sending email shows error

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i'm trying to send email in laravel 5.1 but getting following error:

```
Class 'Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport' not found
```

My code:

```
public function test_mail() {
  $data = ['name' => 'XXX xxx xxx', 'number' => 1234];
  $sent = Mail::send('emails.fee_pay_success', ['data' => $data], function ($m) use ($data) {
        $m->to('abcd@gmail.com', 'Abcd Efg')->subject('Your Reminder!');
    });
 if( ! $sent) dd("something wrong");
dd("send");
}
```

My config file mail.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

   // 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'port' =>465,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => 'tucell@onlinefeepayment.in', 'name' => 'DU'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    //'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' =>'',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

];
```

Comment: Check your smtp server. Is it installed/run in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `\` in `Mail` facade:

```
  $sent = \Mail::send('emails.fee_pay_success', ['data' => $data], function ($m) use ($data) {
```

Because in your config file you are using `smtp` server, looks like your machine does not have a smtp server to process email server. Try downloading [FakeSMTP server](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/download.html), it is a small jar file that will emulate an smtp server for debbuging purposes.

Comment: I don't think you need a backslash when using Facades.

Comment: Yes, you need to. When you use facades inside of classes declared with a namespace, by default php will try load the facade as a class member from the same namespace where controller in question belongs to.

Comment: " All facades live in the global namespace" -  That's why you need to put a backslash. Or if you want to make an unnecessary import then do `use Mail;` This guy forgot the symbol

Comment: Create a namespaced controller, then call, for example, `Session::put('foo', 'bar');` in a function. Will crash your script.

Comment: I assumed OP had `use Mail` already. Still, if `Mail` facade was not loaded, he would've gotten `class Mail not found` error. So probably, the package is incomplete.

Comment: Well, if the class is imported with `use`, there is no need for that. A good point, but it probably does not resolve the issue, because the facade is resolved, but the right class not found.

Comment: Maybe, as you said, if the facade loads then another error is coming.  Looks like he is using `smtp` but his machine has not such mail server.

Comment: @Muhammet, apologies this is not my best day. I will take it easy.